# Java Web Start application gets unrestricted access but still asks for permission

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a Java Web Start (Java 8u121) application that should  run with full access on the users system.

All requirements to run with full access have been taken, basically we are using webstart-maven-plugin to sign the full application (all jars) with an official certificate. The JNLP requests 'all-permissions'. This also sets several properties to the MANIFEST.MF in each jar.

When I start the application (see image) it requests 'unrestricted access'.

[image: Application Starting]

When running the application, it tries to download a few images from another webserver, this always causes the following dialog:

[image]

The stacktrace of the thread showing the dialog is as follows:

```
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.ui.JavawsSysRun.delegate(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0000000081e16908> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.DeploySysRun.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.DeploySysRun$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.DeploySysRun.executePrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.ui.UIFactory.showApiDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.ui.UIFactoryImpl.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.ui.UIFactoryImpl.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.ApiDialog.askUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.ApiDialog.askUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.ApiDialog.askConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkURLPermissionHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.URLtoSocketPermission(Unknown Source)

...

    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The biggest problem with this is that the dialog asking for permission often appears behind our main screen (but it will still block input to the main screen).

I have been able to trace this problem to the `ForkJoinPool`. Which apparently always runs with extra protection. See [this post](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-December/012123.html) by Doug Lea.

What is the best way to disable this? I would prefer this to be an application wide solution.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom executor when using CompletableFuture in combination java web start. See why here http://blog.aggregat4.net/posts/2015-04-14-caution-advised-when-using-the-java-forkjoinpool-or-parallel-streams-with-a-securityManager.html

```
 public static final ExecutorService SWING_POOL = Executors
        .newFixedThreadPool(10, new ThreadFactory() {
            private int count = 0;

            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread t = new Thread(r, "swing-executor-pool-" + count++);
                t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                return t;
            }
        }); 
  //...
  supplyAsync(() -> doStuff(), SWING_POOL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions to this.

First of all you can use [`AccessController.doPriviledged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged-java.security.PrivilegedAction-) inside the task running on the `ForkJoinPool`.

Alternatively you can disable the `SecurityManager` for your full application by calling `System.setSecurityManager(null)` at the start of your application (outside the code running on the `ForkJoinPool`.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned here , Images are getting downloaded from **another** web server , means a new **untrusted** connection is getting fired from jvm. which cause jvm to invoke a security prompt. If you want to avoid this popup dialog ,simply embed your images in the jar file and move to the web server directory hosting your java web start application .Then, add this jar file in resource tag with lazy download strategy. Finally, use [DownloadService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html) service implementation to load jar file resource when needed.

Comment: This is not the case for my (unrestricted) application, because connections to the same server, on different Threads (not in ForkJoinPool) are allowed without any warning (so if I disable the connections on the ForkJoinPool, no warnings appear at all).